# How do I "print" the value of objects to the console with Go's Delve and Visual Studio Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I have the "Delve" debugger setup for Go with Visual Studio code and a super simple program. If I set a breakpoint, and I want to print a variable declared earlier, I'm used to being able to say `po foo` to print out the value of the object foo to the console, but Visual Studio Code just complains about "expected 'EOF'".

How do I print? If I wanted to test things out by printing out values, does Delve not support that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In debug console type `foo` (without `po` prefix)